# Maximum call stack size exceeded with backbone inheritance

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to create a plug able point of sale interface using backbone as framework.

So I have an main.js file that use as entry point and base model for the entire application defined like this:

```
(function (pos) {
    pos.point_of_sale_plugins = Backbone.PoSPlugin.extend({
        init: function () {
            pos_db();         
            pos_models();     
            pos_basewidget(); 
            pos_widgets();    
        }
    });

})(pos);
```

Then I could extend on a file named plugin_one.js like this:

```
(function (pos) {
    pos.point_of_sale_plugins = point_of_sale_plugins.extend({
        init: function () {
            var self = this;
            // Call original init function
            point_of_sale_plugins.__super__.init.call(this);
            // Call tables initialization
            pos_restaurant_db();           
            pos_restaurant_models();        
            pos_restaurant_screens();       
            pos_restaurant_widgets();       
        }
    });
})(pos);
```

The problem is that if I try to extend the function on a file named plugin_two.js it trough a Maximum call stack size exceeded. I use to develop on python, that's why I'm trying to make the inheritance like that, don't know if I could do like that on javascript or I'm missing a very basic point and must work on a total different way.

This is the content of my plugin_two.js file

```
(function (pos) {

    pos.point_of_sale_plugins = point_of_sale_plugins.extend({
        init: function () {
            var self = this;
            // Call original init function
            point_of_sale_plugins.__super__.init.call(this);
            // Include synchronization features
            pos_sync();            
        }
    });
})(pos);
```

Comment: Just corrected the code. pos.point_of_sale_plugins try to be the base class function to call for init the real app.

Comment: Yea, that's right. I'm going to try on a different way today.